# remove bottom panel in xfce

Tags: debian

How remove the bottom panel in xfce

I am using vmware VM debian-10.0.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1

[image]

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all requested information to the question instead of answering in comments.

Comment: Your desktop environment would likely either be "GNOME" or "KDE".  Someone may be able to tell just by the screenshot but I don't have enough experience with the GUIs to know for sure.

Comment: why always give a negative vote I dont understand, or I should ask "what is the meaning of life" It is good question?

Comment: Asterix.  You got downvotes probably because: 1) Your question could have more easily been googled, 2) Your question contains almost no detail, 3) You have been asked for more information and didn't respond, 4) You answered your question as an edit rather than an answer (I know you have since answered, but not before the downvotes).

Comment: okay, your assumptions are invalid.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that but here: have another downvote ;)

Comment: The original question was impossible to answer. We need to know the desktop environment. This is more relevant (for this question) than distro or version. On Microsoft's windows desktop environment is inseparably tied to version, but not in Gnu/Linux or other Unixes.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the bottom panel, right click in the panel, then click the <kbd>-</kbd> button.

Answer (score 0):

Just click control + right click on the panel then go to panel then click panel preferences.At the top of the window choose panel 2 then click  symbol which is in the right end of panel 2